# Apply Range Validation for Input Value AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

When an user entering a value, system should check whether this value is within the range of Minimum and Maximum defined for this field. also, need check for number of decimal points allowed.

```
<input  ng-model='data.value1' >
<input  ng-model='data.value2' >
<input  ng-model='data.value3' >
<input  ng-model='data.value4' >
```

Comment: Use regular expression for this.

Comment: You can also check value using javaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extending My comment:

```
 var range = 'your range';
 var checkRange = function () {
    var value = data.value;
    if(value <=range) {
    //your code;
    } else {
    //your code;
    }
}
```

Update:

```
$scope.data.value = 500;
$scope.$watch('data.value', function (oldVal,newVal) {
     if(newVal > 1000 ) {
      $scope.data.value = 500;
}

})
```

Comment: Consider if I have 5 textbox controls and for all I need to do this same validation. And, if user entered a value which is not fall in the range then, I should reset the entered value to its old value.

Comment: You should use regular expression for this. I don't know what is your range, but there are many ways to do this.

Comment: Help me on one thing... I want to reset to old value if the given value is invalid. if my range is 10-1000 and my current/default value is 500. if user enters 1200, then i should reset back to 500.

Comment: Ok.. I am writing a solution for this.

Comment: Thanks.. should i need to pass these oldVal and newVal?

Comment: No. just use as it is in your controller. You don't need to pass any value to oldVal and newVal.

Comment: its working, but consider my initial value is 500, am changing it to 501, and then 1001. now it should replace with 500. but now it is replacing 501.

Comment: Please see my question updated with more number of textboxes. In your solution, we should mention the model name like 'data.value'. is there any way to have a generic way to do this same validation for all input boxes? the ranges also not same for all textboxes.

Comment: Yes.  but I think you should use custom validation for this. Doing this with the help of only JS will make it complex.

Answer (score 5):

you can add type="number". and for angularJS

```
<input type="number"
       ng-model=""
       [name=""]
       [min=""]
       [max=""]
       [required=""]
       [ng-required=""]
       [ng-minlength=""]
       [ng-maxlength=""]
       [pattern=""]
       [ng-pattern=""]
       [ng-change=""]>
```

Follow the link for more clarification
[AngularJs Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bnumber%5D)

Comment: If it is `type="number"`, you could use `ng-max` and `ng-min`